# Get Rails Activerecord to use external API id for database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, activerecord, redux

I have my project making api fetches for "things" from my react front end and placing them in my redux state. When someone wants to add a review to one these "things" I have an onclick action on "add review" button which posts the "thing" to my database. This is so I can start to build relationships with that thing(I want users to be able to add reviews to it). The issue is the api gives the thing an id that the reviews want to reference when I add it. Active record on the other hand knows nothing about the api id and just gives it a normal primary key type of id and I get an error "Couldn't find a thing with id of 43565" because in my db it has as id of "3" or something. I have already tried serializing id attribute to make it show the api_id, but that didn't help. Any idea how I can address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create action you could initialize the object with the `params.except(:api_id)` and then manually assign it.

```
def create
  thing = Thing.new(params.except(:api_id))
  thing.id = params[:api_id]
  thing.save!
end
```

And then you could perform whatever serialization or validations you wanted

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much. However, I realize a) this is not best practice and b) I lose out on some methods like ```Thing.first``` and other ar query methods because it would return "untruthful" information. Do you have any tips about this?

Comment: You could maybe keep the id convention that Rails has and instead create an `api_id` or w/e you want to call it, column. Then when accessing params from your React app, you could look for the api id and still have the default db id column.